# Re-orient meshes onto normal of surface in geometry nodes

Tags: geometry-nodes

I am trying to convert the Buoys on this imported ocean mesh back into instances.

I know it would have been a better workflow to just set these up in GN in the first place but I'm having to work with someone who uses another 3d Software so I'm hoping I  can find a workaround for this.

[image]

I've managed to position the new instances (Blue) on the original via a 'mesh to points' setup like below, but the part I'm struggling with is how to align the normals/rotation so they are exactly inline.

I'm trying a raycast node to get the normal at the projected point on the ocean surface but I think I'm missing something as it's still a bit misaligned from the original? (See below)

[image]

Any help would be greatly appreciated thank you!

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First things first: you cannot simply plug the *Hit Normal* into the *Rotation*. You have to use an *Align Euler to Vector* node to "convert" the normal into the rotation you want.

To do that, plug the *Hit Normal* into the *Vector* input of the *Align Euler to Vector* node, set that to align the *Z* axis. Leave the *Pivot* at *Auto*. Then plug the output into the *Rotation* of the *Instance on Points* node.

To make the new buoys not float in the air but sit on the ocean faces like the original ones, I've also changed the buoy's origin to the bottom center, then used the *Hit Position* output in a *Set Position* node to place them on the surface.

However, if you now look at the result it is still not perfect - I actually don't know how exactly the *Raycast* node works in this case, I use it rarely... I guess the problem is it's shooting straight down, while the points are offset in normal direction above the faces:

[image: aligned with raycast]

What I would do instead, since the original buoys seem to be oriented with the quad face's normal which they are placed upon, is take a *Sample Nearest* node set to *Face* to get the indices of the nearest faces and plug the *Index* output then into two *Sample Index* nodes set to *Vector* and *Face*, one to sample the *Normal*, the other to sample the *Position*. These outputs you can use for the *Align Euler to Vector* and *Set Position* nodes and the result will be more accurate:

[image: aligned with sampled index]

It probably would have worked even better if you would just use the base of the original bouys in the vertex group to get the position and normal of the surface.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a slightly different approach, using *Geometry Proximity* and a captured face-normal instead of *Raycast*. I  guess how robust this is might depend on how the original instances were distributed. If on faces, it might be safe ground, for this particular job.

[image]

This is the result:

[image]

[image]

Comment: That's a great solution, although if too close together or if the ocean is animated (Moving up & down for example) the buoys can begin to flicker on/off. Would there be a way to lock there position from the first frame so it's almost more like a surface deform?

Comment: Hello, @JaRa.. I thought this one might be a bit shaky... What springs to mind, without resorting to simulation, is: On frame 0, read/write proximal UV coordinates. Set instances to corresponding P and N. On subsequent frames, read-only, sample P and N  from instance-captured UV. Will give this a shot if you need it.. I'm a bit pushed for time over the next few days.

Comment: Ok thanks so much for that I'll give it a go but would still love to see your results as I'm sure you'll create a much more streamlined version.... And no worries at all I'm not under any time pressure so just whenever you are feeling more free'd up :)